# How do I copy an Excel sheet from my active workbook TO a closed workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am simply trying to copy sheet 3 from my open workbook over to a closed workbook but I get a runtime error. How do I do this?

```
Sub vba_copy_sheet()
Dim mybook As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set mybook = _
    Workbooks.Open _
    ("C:\Folder Path\Closed File.xlsx")
    
   Sheets(3).Copy Before:=mybook.Sheets(1)
    mybook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which workbook is the sheets (3), just specify the sheets (3) that are the current workbook.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Copy Before:=mybook.Sheets(1)
```

[image]